# flask wtforms stays empty after submit

Tags: flask, flask-login

My code is :
routes.py:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()  # None if invalid
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        return redirect('dashapp')

    print(form.errors)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
    <h3>Log in</h3>
    <div class="row">
    <form>
        <div class="col-md-4">

            {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = Column(String(128))
    is_admin = Column(Boolean, default=False)


    def set_password(self, password):

        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):

        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
```

on submit my form is still empty so It did not pass form.validate_on_submit().
I tried to simplify as you can see my code but it still not working

form data object is username:none, password:none, Submit:False.
CSFR Token is not empty So the issue is not from there.

Please find my form:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = StringField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Log In')
```

Comment: Add also your form definition so we can see all picture

Comment: Didn't work with quick_form, but I see that you shouldn't put it inside <form> tag. It can be that you have two forms on your page

Comment: @Dmitry was right, you should remove `<form>` tag,  have a look at this post on Medium https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-flask-wtforms-faab71d5a034

Answer (score 2):

my correction removing form tag:
thanks to @Dimitry and @cizario

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
    <h3>Log in</h3>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">

            {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
        </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```